# Using dependency injection with NLog

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nlog

I'm using NLog as my logger, however I cant seem to find an `Ilogger` interface in NLog namespaces unlike log4net's `Ilogger` interface, do I have to create my own wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a wrapping interface only if you expect to use a different logging technology in the future or if you need to mock the logger for unit testing; if not, the dependency injector will probably let you register concrete instances of the logging class you are using.

Comment: If you use a wrapper for NLog how do you continue to use features such as Trace? They report 1 level back in the stacktrace which ends up being the wrapper object not the problematic code you are trying to trace? Any thoughts on this? Or links?